# server is giving me the following error msxml3.dll

Tags: asp-classic, serverxmlhttp, msxml3

I'm using classic ASP and Server.XMLHTTP. My code has been working for years and all of a sudden today, across different servers, i get this error:

```
msxml3.dll error 80072f7d
```

All the multiple servers are all calling the same server that's called the Mother Machine. I've rebooted the mother machine and restarted services but nothing. I've also when to the URL that the XMLHttp call is calling up and it comes up fine.

How can I fix it?

Comment: The current version is msxml6.dll - `Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")`

Comment: it could be caused by the server you're reading XML from. Have a look at http://www.44342.com/exchange-server-f89-t1512-p1.htm or http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/ASP/Q_20380286.html

Comment: @Damien Maybe this will help [Err Msg: An Error Occurred in the Secure Channel Support (MS Support)](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;Q216539&)

Comment: @Damien I would first follow John's suggestion and update your `ServerXMLHTTP` to the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

In Microsoft Windows Server 2003, applications that use the Cryptography API (CAPI) cannot validate an X.509 certificate. This problem occurs if the certificate is secured by the Secure Hash Algorithm 2 (SHA2) family of hashing algorithms. Applications may not work as expected if they require the SHA2 family of hashing algorithms.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938397 fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this exact same problem on our Windows Server 2003 SP2 site with both our Paypal and UPS integration, only a couple days apart:

```
msxml6.dll error '80072f7d'
An error occurred in the secure channel support
```

I got the same error whether using MSXML6 or MSXML3 didn't matter.

**[This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/938397)** MSKB Hotfix solved the problem.
Request and download the file. Move to server, in a temp folder. Execute the compressed file. Then execute the resultant patch file.
Reboot the server.
Everything back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Follow those Steps:

1. Check server log for recent updates - was something downloaded recently that applied changes?
2. Check the hardware - specifically your **network card on the mother machine** - may became faulty.
3. I cannot see a fix to a code that is running for years as a solution - the problem is probably not within the code.

Comment: I've pin pointed it down to having something to do with the ssl cert. If i use the domain https://blah.com, it doesn't work... if i use http://blah.com then it does. I've uninstalled/re-installed/re-keyed the ssl cert to no avail... any ideas?

Comment: hmm.. check it on a different machine. 1st step is to acknowledege the problem is with the machine itself and not other network assets.